# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery

hello i am trying to link these js codes into my webpage with the code on the php as this:

```
<script src="./js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is the code and its coming with this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });

});
```

thanks

Comment: You need to include jquery also.

Comment: jQuery is not included or included correctly?

Comment: Do you have jquery included in your file?

Comment: Have you included jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jquery too:

```
<!-- using google CDN -->    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery Library and make sure that you import jquery before yours js.

Try adding this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```